# Does ITopologicalOperator.Simplify call IGeometry.SnapToSpatialReference?

Tags: arcobjects

Does the ITopologicalOperator.Simplify method call IGeometry.SnapToSpatialReference as part of the simplify process?

I thought I saw some ESRI documentation that indicated that it does, but I cannot find it now.   I would prefer not to make a redundant call if it is not needed.  If you have a link to ESRI documentation indicating that it does, please include it.

Comment: What artifacts do you expect if this call is not done?

Comment: The help file does not explicitly state that it calls SnapToSpatialReference but it does say _"The XY tolerance property of the geometry's associated spatial reference is used during the simplify operation for polylines and polygons."_, maybe this is what you are observing?

Comment: @0kcats - I would expect to sometimes not get proper simplification if two points that would have snapped together are not snapped prior to the Simplify call or to get a different answer from IRelationalOperator queries when snapping would cause points on different features to become coincident when previously they were just close.

Comment: @Preston Relational operator uses tolerance. The tolerance should be 10 times or more larger than the resolution. Therefore, the snapping should not influence your results. If the feature has not been saved yet, it might change a little after it was saved due to compression for example.

Comment: It may or may not snap. You should not experience issues if your tolerance is at least 10 times grid resolution.